# race condition when calling super.paint jframe

Tags: java

I'm trying to fill the entire canvas with `fillRect`. Whenever I include `super.paint()` in the beginning of the overridden `paint` method, `super.paint()` sometimes gets called after the `fillRect`, causing unpredictable behavior on whether `super.paint()` gets drawn first or `drawRect`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DebugJFrameRace extends JFrame {
    public DebugJFrameRace () {
        super("Debug race");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        
        // clear background
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
        
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DebugJFrameRace app = new DebugJFrameRace ();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


}
```

Comment: I am able to create a black frame every time by using your code.  Could you provide better context so we can __understand__ and __reproduce__ your problem?

Comment: I am using openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04 on Ubuntu 18.04 installed via `sudo apt install default-jre default-jdk`. To reproduce the problem, I simply did `javac DebugJFrameRace.java && java DebugJFrameRace` a lot of times

Answer (score 2):

I don't have problems with the posted code.

I'm not really sure what it is designed to demonstrate. A black background is always painted.

However, the posted code does not follow Swing guidelines:

1. All Swing components should be created and updated on the `Event Dispach Thread (EDT)`. This is done by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples on how to better structure your code. Not executing the code on the EDT can cause random problems.
2. You should not override paint() in a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` on a `JPanel` and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.